# Chrome on pc returns true on touch device check in JS

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, touch

I have always used this to detect touch device in my scripts:

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

Now Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m returns true on my PC.

http://jsfiddle.net/zRZD8/

What is wrong? How can I detect touch device in better way?

Comment: Returns `false` for me. Same version, Win7.

Comment: and for me true, after restart - too... win7

Answer (score 0):

Also returns false for me in same browser.
might your screen is touch contemptible? :)

Comment: Hm, my screen is not touch compatible, but I have a graphic tablet connected to PC... maybe it causes a problem? But it have definetly started with a last chrome version...